# Como obtener cookies con angularjs desde la respuesta http del servidor

Tags: c#, angularjs, .net, http

quería consultar lo siguiente, tengo una aplicación que utiliza CORS, y necesito obtener la cookie que me retornan los ws de la web api. 
Observando en el navegador veo que la cookie va en el header como Set-Cookie.
Ya probe con ngCookies de AngularJS (Angular 1) y no funciona. En el servidor uso .net con c# y CookieAuthentication de Owin.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna opcion diferente??

```
this._$http.post('http://webapi:50830'+Utiles.prefijoApi(this._subscriptor) + 'cuenta/login', JSON.stringify(dto))
       .then(function (resultado) {
       var a = this._$cookies.get('Token');
           return resultado.data;
       }.bind(this), function (error) {
           return this._$q.reject(error.data);
       }.bind(this));
```

**EDICION**

**Resolvi el problema con el  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; y funciona correctamente para las peticiones a la WebApi. Ahora bien, tengo el mismo problema con las peticiones a los controllers MVC, y no encuentro forma de resolverlo, alguna idea??**

Answer (score 0):

puedes incluir [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies), agregas la referencia al archivo `.js`

```
<script src="js/angular-cookies.js">
```

Y tambien a tu modulo `['ngCookies']` y finalmente en tu controlador haces la inyeccion `$cookies`

```
$cookies.get('Token');
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48223/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-como-obtener-cookies-con-angularjs-desde-la-respu).

Comment: hola sioesi, resolví el problema para la llamada a los Web services. Ahora bien tengo el mismo problema con la llamada a los controllers MVC, no envía la cookie en la petición y la necesito, tenes alguna idea de como se pude resolver??

Comment: Como no la envia? Ahora puedes capturarla desde angular?

Comment: No desde angular no la puedo capturar, pero al poner el $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; envía la cookie automaticamente en la llamada a los WebServices, pero no en la llamada a los controllers MVC

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de angularJS puedes obtener los headers de la respuesta.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Solamente tienes que indicárselo a la función que ejecutas dentro del "then":

```
this._$http.post('http://webapi:50830'+Utiles.prefijoApi(this._subscriptor) + 'cuenta/login', JSON.stringify(dto))
       .then(function (resultado, status, headers) {
       var a = headers['Set-Cookie'];

           return resultado.data;
       }.bind(this), function (error) {
           return this._$q.reject(error.data);
       }.bind(this));
```

También puedes hacer un console.log(headers) para asegurarte de que el contenido que buscas está ahí.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hice eso y Headers es undefined, no se que puede ser, probé de muchas formas y no funciona ninguna.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes acceso al los response headers en tu app de AngularJS (Angular 1), otra manera de mantener tu Token dentro de la app es con:

> $window.localStorage

Creas un servicio (factory) y ahí declaras tu setToken y getToken.

```
angular.module('app').factory('nombreDelServicio', ['$window', nombreDelServicio]);

function nombreDelServicio($window) {
    var storage = $window.localStorage;
    var cachedToken;
    setToken: function(token) {
      cachedToken = token;
      storage.setItem('token', angular.toJson(token));
    },
    getToken: function() {
      if(!cachedToken)
        cachedToken = storage.getItem('token');

      return cachedToken;
    }
}
```

Inyectas tu servicio al controlador y cuando recibes los headers de la web api asignas el token de esta manera:

```
nombreDelServicio.setToken(response.headers('nombre-de-tu-header'));
```

Cuando quieras leer tu token de esta manera:

```
var token = nombreDelServicio.getToken();
```

También existe un módulo que para ocupar el window local storage se llama: [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: Así tampoco me funciono, con el  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; resolvi el problema para la llamada a los web services. Ahora el problema que tengo es con la llamada a los controllers MVC, que necesito también recibir la cookie y no la recibo.